# Does javac optimize object files (*.class)?

Tags: java

I'm trying to limit changes from a jar file. I introduced a fix on the code, a very small fix in a single file. Javac compiler generates the new .class file and I plan to replace **ONLY** this single file in the jar (we had problems with the build and are unsure if the current build matches the production build).

I'm a C++ pro, but java... not so much. I wouldn't dare to do this in C++ as optimizers inline a lot of stuff from object files and static libs. I'm under the impression I can do this with no great consequences in java.

Any advice?

Comment: Remember that a single java file can generate multiple .class files if inner classes are involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually hot deploy files on server, that creates no problem in JAVA. You can **do it as long as your compiler version is same** as the other files. It would not be a problem.

Comment: Ok, check, but I was using java(64-bits). Can I compile using the javac64 in x86 env? Again, I know I can compile C++ x32 or x64 under x32. How about java?

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification defines [binary compatibility](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html) between class files. In general, class files tend to be much more compatible than they would be in C, so you'll probably be ok. However, there are a few gotchas, such as `static final` fields (constants) which *are* inlined by the compiler.

In any case, the situation in which you are not sure what code code you have running in production, I would consider to be **very** dangerous, and try to fix as soon as possible.

Comment: We are about 99% sure (binary compared the files), but we are on the brisk of production deployment. So we are doing this to buy some time. Thanks about static code hint. And, no there is no static in the modification.